# Get last modification date of most recently modified article

Tags: articles, date

As a way of presenting the "freshness" of my website's content, I want to present the date of the most recently created/modified article.

I need to display the last change date across all articles on my home page.

I know I can get an individual article's last modification date like this:

```
$this->item->modified
```

But the question is : **Can I get the last change date for all articles?**

Comment: Are you adding the last modified date to a list of articles that is already on the page? Or do you need to make a new database call to get the data and then display it?

Comment: @jamesgarrett I believe I need to make the database call as I need the last modification date for all the articles on the website. The goal is to display the last modification date of the website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SQL that returns the most recent modified date across all your articles:

`` SELECT `modified` FROM `#__content` GROUP BY `modified` ORDER BY `modified` DESC LIMIT 1 ``

Then you would need to build a [Joomla select query](https://docs.joomla.org/Selecting_data_using_JDatabase) in PHP:

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query->select($db->quoteName(array('modified')));
$query->from($db->quoteName('#__content'));
$query->group('modified');
$query->order('modified DESC');
$db->setQuery($query);
$mostrecent = $db->loadResult();
echo $mostrecent;
```

You would then further convert the result into a date (as the result is returned as a string) and then adjust how your most recent date is formatted:

```
$thedate = date_create($mostrecent);
echo '<em>Site content last modified on '. date_format($thedate,'l jS F Y').'<em>';
```

Which at the time of my reply would return:

*Site content last modified on Saturday 11th December 2021*

Comment: BTW To test that, I've used Regular Labs Sourcerer extension to place the code into an article by pasting the above code between `{source}<?php ?>{/source}` tags.

Comment: Tested on a live site and it works great. I added it in an article override. Thank you !